# How to switch between different views in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

So I'm working on a custom language interpreter for VSCode, and I want to be able to switch between a custom HTML view and the raw xml-like view.

Currently I have VSCode correctly detecting the language when I load in a file, but I am lost on how I get it to load the HTML rendering of the file.

Basically like the way that Intellij handles README.md files where it shows a preview and you can toggle between the preview and editor mode.

Basically trying to figure out how to get it to flip between the two modes.  I assume there's some vscode hookup between the two and I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I don't get it. Is your custom language just XML?

Comment: It's an extension of xml specific to Apache Daffodil

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I'm looking for is a custom editor, not a preview mode.  Just wasted tons of time googling the wrong stuff.

Documentation can be found here.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors